# How to get a list of existing Web Audio contexts in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api

Is there a way to get a list of currently instantiated Web Audio contexts in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get this list in Javascript, then no, there's no way to get that in Chrome.  chrome://media-internals will give you some idea, but it will be mixed in with audio/video tags and such.  And there's no way to go from media-internals to the actual WebAudio context.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found its take a heap snapshot.
[I hope it`s help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUyTg.png)